# Create Custom Path Macros in Visual Studio

Tags: macros, visual-studio-2013

I would like to create custom Path Macros in Visual Studio. I know there is [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710084/visual-studio-where-to-define-custom-path-macros) on this but that one only works for Visual **C++** projects. I'm **not** writting a C++ project so the Property Manager isn't available.

Comment: You'll have to edit the project file by hand and add an property to a `<PropertyGroup>`.  The lack of support in the IDE to change the property value makes it less than practical.

Comment: @HansPassant No solution wide solution?

Comment: All projects can `<Import>` a common .targets file with the property.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I don't want to take the time to write it up properly, it just isn't very useful.

Comment: @HansPassant What file would have a `<PropertyGroup>`?

Comment: It's ridiculous that custom properties can't be added at solution level.