# Where to define Macros in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, macros

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and wanted to use some Macros from the C++ Eigen Library ([these](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html)), but I don't know how to. I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710084/visual-studio-where-to-define-custom-path-macros), but their solutions don't work for VS2013.

**EDIT - Answer :**

The question that I linked already had the answer from user @Cam Jackson. Actually, I didn't know that Property Manager (View -> Other windows -> Property Manager) is not the same thing as the "Right-click -> Properties" of the project. I'm quoting the answer :

> 'User Macros' will only display under 'Common Properties' if the property sheet that you're editing is specific to the project/solution! So what you need to do is open the Property Manager window in VS, right-click on your project and add a new property sheet. Then right-click->Properties on the newly created sheet, and you will now see the 'User Macros' option underneath 'Common Properties'! Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, that works fine in VS2013 as well.

Comment: You can post your answer as an actual Answer to the question, instead of an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question that I linked already had the answer from user @Cam Jackson. Actually, I didn't know that the Property Manager (View -> Other windows -> Property Manager) is not the same thing as the "Right-click -> Properties" of the project. I'm quoting the answer :

> 'User Macros' will only display under 'Common Properties' if the property sheet that you're editing is specific to the project/solution! So what you need to do is open the Property Manager window in VS, right-click on your project and add a new property sheet. Then right-click->Properties on the newly created sheet, and you will now see the 'User Macros' option underneath 'Common Properties'! Hope that helps :)